# How to modify data frame in R based on one unique column

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame that looks like this.

**Data**

```
Denmark         MG301
Denmark         MG302
Australia       MG301
Australia       MG302
Sweden          MG100
Sweden          MG120
```

I need to make a new data frame based on unique values of 2nd columns while removing repeating values in Denmark. And results should look like this

**Data**

```
Australia       MG301
Australia       MG302
Sweden          MG100
Sweden          MG120
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, could you kindly provide a reproducible data set/example with your question? This would help find a solution to your question :)

Comment: Are you sure that your data is correct?

Comment: Have removed *repeating* values in Denmark or *all* of them?

Comment: I want to remove repeating values overall regardless of Denmark but it can be done for Denmark too. I am not sure I made a point

Comment: @RobinTurkington
Cohort= c("UK","UK","UK","Sweden","Sweden","Sweden","France","France","France")
IDs=c("Fam100","Fam123","Fam306","Fam232","Fam123","Fam160","Fam323","Fam129","Fam330")
df=data.frame(Cohort,IDs)
df

You can see UK and sweden both have fam123 in common, I want to keep just one of them and disregard other.

Answer (score 1):

**Update after clarification:**

This code keeps all distinct values in column2:

```
distinct(df, code, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
1 Denmark   MG301
2 Australia MG302
3 Sweden    MG100
4 Sweden    MG120
```

**First answer:**
I am not quite sure. But it gives the desired output:

```
df %>% 
  filter(country != "Denmark")
```

Output:

```
  country   code 
  <chr>     <chr>
1 Australia MG301
2 Australia MG302
3 Sweden    MG100
4 Sweden    MG120
```

data:

```
df<- tribble(
  ~country, ~code,
"Denmark", "MG301", 
  "Denmark", "MG301", 
  "Australia", "MG301", 
  "Australia", "MG302", 
  "Sweden", "MG100", 
  "Sweden", "MG120")
```

Comment: I want to keep unique values in second column whether it results in removing any of the variables from first columns.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, the following code removes all rows with `"Denmark"` in the first column and all duplicated 2nd column by groups of 1st column.

```
i <- df1$V1 != "Denmark"
j <- as.logical(ave(df1$V2, df1$V1, FUN = duplicated))
df1[i & !j, ]
#         V1    V2
#3 Australia MG301
#4 Australia MG302
#5    Sweden MG100
#6    Sweden MG120
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just distinct ? then this may help

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("denmark", "denmark", "Australia", "Australia", "Sweden", "Sweden"), B = c("MG301","MG302","MG301","MG302","MG100","MG100"))

df %>% distinct()

          A     B
1   denmark MG301
2   denmark MG302
3 Australia MG301
4 Australia MG302
5    Sweden MG100
```

Or you want this ?

```
df %>% 
    group_by(B) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(A = first(A))
```

```
  B     A      
* <chr> <chr>  
1 MG100 Sweden 
2 MG301 denmark
3 MG302 denmark
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `duplicated` with a `!` bang operator to remove duplicated rows among that column.
To show a rather complicated case, I am adding one row in Denmark which is not duplicated and hence should not be filtered out.

```
df<- tribble(
  ~country, ~code,
  "Denmark", "MG301", 
  "Denmark", "MG302",
  'Denmark', "MG303",
  "Australia", "MG301", 
  "Australia", "MG302", 
  "Sweden", "MG100", 
  "Sweden", "MG120")

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  country   code 
  <chr>     <chr>
1 Denmark   MG301
2 Denmark   MG302
3 Denmark   MG303
4 Australia MG301
5 Australia MG302
6 Sweden    MG100
7 Sweden    MG120

df %>% 
  mutate(d = duplicated(code)) %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  mutate(d = sum(d)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  filter(!(d > 0 & country == 'Denmark'))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  country   code      d
  <chr>     <chr> <int>
1 Denmark   MG303     0
2 Australia MG301     1
3 Australia MG302     1
4 Sweden    MG100     0
5 Sweden    MG120     0
```